# How to add an onclick jquery function in an input area

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am a newbie in Javascript and jquery I have a jquery function

```
$('.input-group .date').datepicker({
    });
```

for

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dp3">
<input class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="Date" name="date" value="">
</div>
```

I want to add this inside input tag using `onclick=""` can you please tell me how to do this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the end? Your question as written makes no sense.

Comment: why you want to make it in onclick?

Comment: BTW, this is wrong selector: `$('.input-group .date')` should be: `$('.input-group.date')`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm thinking what your thinking then it's wrong.

`.datepicker()` already assigns an `onClick` event so you don't have to create an extra one.
You have to make sure you are using jQuery and jQuery UI in order for `datepicker` to work.

Then you either have to put your script before you close `body` or in the head and use

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

I also think you are using the wrong selector here.

`.` is class
`#` is ID

So it should be

```
$('.input-group .form-control').datepicker();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/AjRm3/

Answer (score 1):

For those coming to this question because they want to know how to bind to the event that happens when someone clicks on an input box, then this is useful:

```
$('input.your-input-box-class').focus(function(e){
    // do something
});
```

For those who want to use `datepicker` like the original question asks, then remember that jQuery UI abstracts away from these types of details.  So just use the widgets like they were meant to be used.  In this case, create the datepickers for all your input boxes that have a certain class (say `date` maybe) when the DOM is done loading:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.datepicker').datepicker({ /*... pass options here ...*/ });
});
```

And for options, you read the documentation, they include handling all the events you need:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Call a function:

`onclick="someFunction(this);"`

Set function:

```
function someFunction(this) {
    $(this).prev('.input-group.date').datepicker({});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You bind datepicker to DOM element, not `onClick`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.form-control').datepicker({});
});
```

Or add it in function, so you can call it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

put the set of code inside a javascript function say clickMe()

```
function clickMe(){
$('.input-group .date').datepicker({
    });
}
```

now call the function in click method.

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dp3">
<input class="form-control" type="text"  placeholder="Date" name="date" value="" onclick="clickMe()">
</div>
```